# DataFrame transform encounters NaN which does not exist in the source data

Tags: python, dataframe

When running `df.transform` some data in the data frame seems to be ambiguous even through source of the data does not contain any `NaN`

```
"None of [Float64Index([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,\n              ...\n              nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],\n             dtype='float64', length=36011)]
```

stepped through the code but still dont understand why dataframe might abbreviate data

### Source

```
import pandas
from sklearn import preprocessing
from datetime import datetime
import numpy


def todatetime(datetime_string):
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return datetime_object

def getdaysdelta(earlier_date_string, later_date_string):
    later_date = todatetime(later_date_string)
    earlier_date = todatetime(earlier_date_string)
    days = (later_date-earlier_date).days
    return days

def getlegend(initial_list):
    working_set = set(initial_list)
    unique_list = list(working_set)
    unique_list.sort()
    legend = []
    for i in range(0, len(unique_list) - 1):
        obj = lambda: None
        obj.value = unique_list[i]
        obj.index = i + 1
        legend.append(obj)
    return legend

def getlegendvalue(initial_value, legend):
    for entry in legend:
        if entry.value == initial_value:
            return entry.index
    outlier_value = initial_value

df = pandas.read_csv(r'data/fires/fire_archive_M6_96619.csv')

df.sort_values('acq_date')
earliestDate = df['acq_date'][0]

# TODO: if there acq_date is not a continues sequence then there will be gaps in gridid
df['date_delta'] = df['acq_date'].transform(lambda x: getdaysdelta(earliestDate, x))
values = df['date_delta'].values
legend = getlegend(values)

# grid id should be an int not a float this happens as `NaN` is added to the list this is where the Nan values start appearing
df['gridid_raw'] = df['date_delta'].transform(lambda x: getlegendvalue(x, legend))
```

#### My source data looks like this

```
latitude,longitude,brightness,scan,track,acq_date,acq_time,satellite,instrument,confidence,version,bright_t31,frp,daynight,type
-11.807,142.0583,313,1,1,2019-08-01,0056,Terra,MODIS,48,6.3,297.3,6.6,D,0
-11.7924,142.085,319.3,1,1,2019-08-01,0056,Terra,MODIS,71,6.3,297.3,11.3,D,0
-12.8398,132.8744,311.6,3.1,1.7,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,42,6.3,298.7,23.1,D,0
-14.4306,143.3035,310.1,1.1,1.1,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,33,6.3,296.1,6.5,D,0
-12.4953,131.4897,310.3,4,1.9,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,36,6.3,298.8,27.6,D,0
-12.6191,142.1998,314.8,1,1,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,68,6.3,297.6,9.3,D,0
-14.3655,143.5682,305.4,1.2,1.1,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,24,6.3,283.9,5.9,D,0
-14.3195,143.5198,322.9,1.2,1.1,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,79,6.3,290.9,20.4,D,0
-13.1654,141.9715,317.2,1,1,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,72,6.3,300,9.9,D,0
-11.5473,132.6796,311.5,3.4,1.7,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,40,6.3,298.7,27.3,D,0
-11.5417,132.649,312.2,3.4,1.7,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,42,6.3,298,31.4,D,0
-11.5471,132.6538,316,3.4,1.7,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,65,6.3,298,52.7,D,0
-12.7626,142.1759,335.2,1,1,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,88,6.3,301.7,30.1,D,0
-12.705,133.907,311.7,2.6,1.5,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,57,6.3,298.6,20.6,D,0
-13.1092,134.1848,315.9,2.4,1.5,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,67,6.3,298.4,29.5,D,0
-14.0539,142.3327,316,1,1,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,52,6.3,298.8,7.8,D,0
-12.6996,133.9138,310.9,2.6,1.5,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,55,6.3,298.7,17.6,D,0
-12.7499,134.5251,314.8,2.3,1.5,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,66,6.3,299.9,22.8,D,0
-12.7141,134.3991,313.9,2.4,1.5,2019-08-01,0057,Terra,MODIS,64,6.3,299.2,23,D,0

# Skippings loads of rows to to end

-16.6833,124.8175,319.8,2.1,1.4,2019-09-30,1641,Aqua,MODIS,99,6.3,294.2,46.3,N,0
-16.689,127.6211,312.4,1.3,1.1,2019-09-30,1641,Aqua,MODIS,85,6.3,297.3,13.9,N,0
-16.687,127.609,320.8,1.3,1.1,2019-09-30,1641,Aqua,MODIS,100,6.3,297.4,25,N,0
-16.7241,124.8292,328.5,2.1,1.4,2019-09-30,1641,Aqua,MODIS,100,6.3,295.1,73.4,N,0
-16.7134,124.8259,343.2,2.1,1.4,2019-09-30,1641,Aqua,MODIS,100,6.3,295.4,136,N,0
-16.7209,124.8104,312.9,2.1,1.4,2019-09-30,1641,Aqua,MODIS,86,6.3,294.3,29,N,0
-16.7117,124.8318,325,2.1,1.4,2019-09-30,1641,Aqua,MODIS,100,6.3,294.9,60.9,N,0
-16.7083,124.8126,315.2,2.1,1.4,2019-09-30,1641,Aqua,MODIS,91,6.3,294.3,33.9,N,0
-29.1196,122.9981,306.7,1.6,1.2,2019-09-30,1644,Aqua,MODIS,69,6.3,287.9,17.8,N,0
-29.1225,123.0141,300.6,1.6,1.2,2019-09-30,1644,Aqua,MODIS,31,6.3,289,10.6,N,0
-28.0557,131.6349,305.2,1.2,1.1,2019-09-30,1644,Aqua,MODIS,63,6.3,292.3,7.9,N,0
-28.0572,131.6473,302.1,1.2,1.1,2019-09-30,1644,Aqua,MODIS,41,6.3,291.7,5.7,N,0
-28.064,131.6209,323.5,1.2,1.1,2019-09-30,1644,Aqua,MODIS,100,6.3,293.9,27.4,N,0
-28.0656,131.6334,312.7,1.2,1.1,2019-09-30,1644,Aqua,MODIS,85,6.3,292.9,14.2,N,0
-28.2625,128.5494,304.9,1,1,2019-09-30,1644,Aqua,MODIS,27,6.3,290.9,6.4,N,0
-28.2941,128.5123,301.7,1,1,2019-09-30,1644,Aqua,MODIS,43,6.3,290.4,5.5,N,0
-28.3001,128.553,303.6,1,1,2019-09-30,1644,Aqua,MODIS,41,6.3,290.3,5.7,N,0
-30.8641,121.4995,309.1,1.8,1.3,2019-09-30,1645,Aqua,MODIS,77,6.3,290.9,23,N,2
```

Comment: provide the code.

Comment: @D.L I have updated the post let me know if you see something I cant

Comment: thanks,  did you see the (general) answer which was posted about 45 mins ago ?  it suggests that the process in the question has produced a NaN... you can inspect for this.

Comment: @D.L like I mentioned in the post I have traced it back all the way to the the `transform` I am sure that `getlegendvalue ` returns no `NaN`. I am not having general problems with `transform`

Answer (score 0):

The transform function (on a dataframe) is relatively straight forward. So there must be an issue with the data.

Here is a simple example which you could work from:

```py
import pandas as pd

# dataframe with integers (no None's)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'B': [4, 5, 6],
                   'C': [7, 8, 9]})

# Calculate mean of columns  
df_means = df.mean()

# Subtract column means 
df_trans = df.transform(lambda x: x - x.mean())

print(df_trans)
```

returns this:

```
     A    B    C
0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

as a side note, i used a `lambda` function in the example, but you could make your own function.